# Copying sequence of files to be physically placed consecutive on hard drive

Tags: linux, windows, macos, file-transfer, file-management

I have a image files sequence that need to be read as fast as they can as long they are really a video divided on frames. So when the image sequence is not written on the hard drive consecutively the performance is poor because the disk arm continously moves the head seeking for each file. 
I need to know how to force files to write in the right order physically on hard drive when copying. OSX, Linux and Windows procedures are needed.
Thanks.

Comment: Does your software require individual files, or can it cope with a single "archive" file (e.g. tar or uncompressed zip)?

Comment: it needs to copy each file to newer location as they was originally. I need to order files on drive, no to compress them.

Comment: Use a SSD/flash memory card to side-step the problem. Also , AFAIK Linux filesystems make a good attempt to keep **a single file** contiguous so you could put all your images in an archive file and then mount the archive using the [archivemount utility](https://www.linux.com/news/mounting-archives-fuse-and-archivemount).

Comment: Not a choice. I cannot change my hardware neither my filesystem. Only need the right tool for reorder file positions on the hard drive.

Comment: Linux: Use extra HD with single partition, directly write the data to the partition. I'm not sure what you mean by "image file sequence"; if you mean already existing files somewhere else, then use `tar`, and write the output directly to the partition. Once you are finished and not any more performance-bound, read the written output, and place it in a proper filesystem. All this will horribly fail if you try to write more data than the size of the partition. You also need two steps.

Comment: @dirkt i meant several image files like tiff, dpx, tga files. They are all part of a movie and they become a sequence, so they are best placed one after each other on a hard drive, so ther would not be seek times that makes lag and lose performance.

Comment: Is the problem "I don't have enough performance when writing data, so I loose some frames" or is the problem "I have lots of files and they don't load fast enough, so video play stutters"? There are some low-level FS tools under Linux, so in principle you *could* arrange everything in contiguous blocks, but very likely your problem would be solved better by preloading.

Answer (score 2):

The [contig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/contig) utility from [Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) is specifically designed to do this for one file at a time in Windows systems with HDD storage.  No equivalent to [contig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/contig) was found for MacOS or Linux.

However, if you use an SSD, please note that data is stored within the cells of the SSD wherever its firmware decides to put it, so any benefit from the file being contiguously written as per NTFS may be negated.

Comment: The contig utility from sysinternals is not for that purpuse. It only defrag single files. It does not sort a sequence of files sequentially in the  hard drive. By the way, I think i made clear is not SSD. As i posted, is a hard drive (not solid state drive), and i told that the arm moves continously the head. SSD dont have arms neither heads. And please dont try to edit my post as long it lost the original meaning and i needed to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really answer this, especially for Linux, Windows, and Mac at once. Because:

- Each different filesystem could put files in a different place on-disk. Try creating an ext3/4 filesystem and take a look at where an easily identifiable file (that contains for example all `a`'s) ends up - it will probably get written in "stripes" across the device.
- Each different hard drive could have an unknown number of platters & heads, and an unknown way they map to sectors
- The operating system or hard drive itself could quietly "remap" sectors to a different on-disk location

In general, it sounds like you just want to avoid file fragmentation, and you can do that by having the filesystem empty (or nearly empty) when you write the files.

---

If you just want to write one specific file after another in whatever order you prefer (but the OS will still ultimately decide where to place them on disk), you could use a loop something like (for example on Linux)

```
while read filename
cp filename destination
sync
done
```

Or have `dd` skip the buffer cache and do some syncing too:

```
dd if=filename of=destination/filename oflags=direct,sync
```

Comment: I now that there are commercial solutions that make this happen, you can check Data Mover from Brisght Technologies. I think that systems reserve space on disk previous to write all the info. I´m not asking for a solution for all the OS but one for each. I know that it depends on filesystems and OS. It rings a bell that rsync could make something like that, but im not sure.

Comment: Data mover doesn't sound like it's mounting volumes directly & doing it's own sector writes, so it must be picking which files to write first & letting the OS do regular writing. Some of the features support that: *"recognizes sequences and lets you manage file based sequences as if they are a single file. That way DataMover proactively prevents fragmented, randomized and interleaved file layout in the beginning"* and just trying to write one file at a time *"Adjust the number of copy threads and copy buffers as you desire. The sequence management makes sure all files are optimally aligned"*

Comment: I think you missunderstood. That software is designed for avoid file sequence fragmentation (and file fragmentation of course).

Comment: But the OS does file writes, a program can't tell the OS exactly where to write files, just which file to write next. Bright Technologies might be doing a little creative writing in their marketing ;-)

Comment: Check Direct IO concepts, man. You will be surprised: "Direct I/O is a feature of the file system whereby file reads and writes go directly from the applications to the storage device, bypassing the operating system read and write caches. Direct I/O is used only by applications (such as databases) that manage their own caches."

Comment: I'm aware of direct I/O, `dd` can do that with `oflag=direct`, if that's the answer you're looking for I could edit it in? But it still uses the OS itself to mount & write files where the OS wants to, it just skips the usual disk buffer caches, one opinion is that *"Overall, this makes I/O slower and does not let Linux do various optimizations that it usually does"*

Comment: That loop you tell does not solve my question. You have no control over the place where you are writing on the hard drive even you are not avoiding file fragmentation neither.

Comment: AFAIK neither does Data Mover from Brightsoft Technologies... it still uses the OS to write files. And as mentioned, even if a program did write files in exactly the sectors it wants, you still run into the hard drive's physical layout problem - a file could easily bridge two different platters, causing the disk arm / head movement you mentioned. If you really *really* wanted, `dd` can write to specific disk sectors, but you'll certainly corrupt the filesystem  without updating the filesystem's FAT/inode-equivalent also, and wouldn't work for mounted filesystems either